# Is there an API endpoint to read, create and update connection settings for a bot channels registration?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-management-api

There is an API call to manage a bot channel registration:

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{{subscriptionId}}/resourcegroups/{{resourceGroupName}}/providers/Microsoft.BotService/botServices/{{botResourceName}}?api-version=2021-05-01-preview`

But the result of this API call doesn't contain any connection settings.

When working from Azure portal, I can see there is a call to `https://dev.botframework.com/api/connectionsettings/GetConnectionSettingItems?botid={{botResourceName}}` which returns a list of connection settings for this bot.

When editing individual connection settings, there are calls to `https://dev.botframework.com/api/connectionsettings/GetServiceProviders?botId={{botResourceName}}` to obtain the possible service providers and `https://dev.botframework.com/api/connectionsettings/GetFullConnectionSettingEx?id={{connectionSettingId}}&botid={{botResourceName}}` to get the configured connection setting properties.

Is this functionality available via Azure management API?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any document support this scenario, I will high recommend you to raise a support ticket to work with support engineer to see any other workaround. If you do not have any support plan, please let me know, I can help on this.

Comment: Thanks for your message. While we do have a support plan, we have never had any benefit from it. We usually get a non-satisfying answer after which the ticket ends up closed. So please, if you can help with this, just write an answer here.